# Mount-DiskImage giving Access Denied when running through remote session

Tags: windows, powershell

I have two VM's(Windows server 2008 r2) with ip

> 172.17.178.10

and

> 172.17.178.11

.
I have created a folder named

> "share"

on vm with ip 172.17.178.10 that has an iso.
I logined into vm with ip 172.17.178.11 and run the following command

> "Mount-DiskImage \\172.17.178.10\share\xyz.iso"

.It mounted successfully i can see the Drive in my computer.
Now i logined into 172.17.178.10 and took a remote session using powershell command

> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 172.17.178.11 -Credential Administrator

.
Now when i run the command

> "Mount-DiskImage \\172.17.178.10\share\xyz.iso"

.
I get the following error:

> MOUNT-DISKIMAGE : Access is denied.
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (MSFT_DiskImage:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_DiskImage) [Mount-DiskImage],
> ```
>
> CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Mount-DiskImage

I have provided full permissions to the

> share

folder.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that powershell remoting will not allow for a second-hop authentication unless credssp is enabled.  Basically what happens is that when when authenticate to the server you are remoting to it only verifies that you have access to it, it does not actually store your credentials for security reasons, so it is not able to connect to any other server in your environment.  I've attached some links below with info on setting up CredSSP, which will allow you to perform second-hop remoting once it is configured.

**https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951608**

**https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849872.aspx**

you could also probably set your share/NTFS permissions to allow everyone read permissions but I have not tested that.

Comment: what about Dismount-DiskImage? It fails in the same way, I am surprised to find that perhaps double-hop is also coming into play when just telling the server to gracefully let that .ISO go...